# Time Counter Script discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I sucessfully did a time count script. The only problem i ran into is when two people are starting the time count (not at the same time) that the script ignores the time from the first person and it's only counting the time for the second person. When either one of them stops the time count it only shows the time from the last person that started the count and i wanna change that but i don't know how.

```js
 case 'start':

            date = new Date();
            message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}> started the time count, don't forget to stop it! `)

            break;


        case 'stop':

            let result = require('pretty-ms')(date ? (new Date() - date) : 0);

            message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}> stopped the time. His time was ` + result)


            break;
```

Comment: Instead of using `date`, try setting `message.author.date`. This will be saved, and different for each user. So instead of `date = new Date()`, do `message.author.date = new Date()` and access it with `message.author.date` instead of `date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the property to the `User` itself. Whenever the cached user is accessed, that property will be accessed with it. Simply change `date` to `message.author.date`

```js
case 'start':
  message.author.date = new Date();
  message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}> started the time count, don't forget to stop it! `)
  break;

case 'stop':
  let result = require('pretty-ms')(message.author.date ? (new Date() - message.author.date) : 0);
  message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}> stopped the time. His time was ` + result)
  break;
```

This can also be done to the `GuildMember` object (`message.member`) to let the same user do this in different guilds!

Answer (score 1):

To save different time for different users and make counter work for both you have to change `date` to `message.author.date` and get such code:

```js
case 'start':

            message.author.date = new Date();
            message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}> started the time count, don't forget to stop it! `)

            break;


        case 'stop':

            let result = require('pretty-ms')(message.author.date ? (new Date() - message.author.date) : 0);

            message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}> stopped the time. His time was ` + result)


            break;
```